# Spring Framework Unable to Resolve References in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I set up a application configuration file for spring, added it to the facets, and set it up according to another configuration file that works perfectly.
All of the references to the spring components are visible and seem to work, but all references to items within the xml file fail to be found.

An example is with the tasks:

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler" />
```

Both taskScheduler and taskExecutor cannot be resolved. As a result, the task bean never gets set up so all of my @Scheduled annotations never work.

Setting up the factory provider for services works just fine (all @Service and @Autowired annotations work), so I am completely certain the issue is with some configuration issue in the project.

What else needs to be configured in IntelliJ for the beans to work? Why does spring not rescan the file to find references to beans?

Here is where all of the springframework beans are referenced:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"
   default-lazy-init="true">
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: The error is that "both taskScheduler and taskExecutor cannot be resolved" so none of the scheduled tasks work. None of the other beans that reference another bean in the spring.xml work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is having multiple contexts for application configuration files. To fix it, go to the configuration file in IntelliJ, then there is a section at the top where you can select which application context you want to put the context file into (Reads something like "Spring Application Context in module [your module]. File is included in [n] contexts"). Try selecting each one until the references resolve; it will remove it from the other contexts. My particular issue was that it was in the MVC context and it needed to be in the Spring Application Context.